# Should I end an expression with ; inside a loop?

Tags: rust

I just started learning Rust and I often have some questions that I can't find any answer. I don't really know how and where to post my question, so I'll try SO.

I started to read the Rust documentation on the website and I did the Guessing game example.

I realized that the `match cmp` expression inside the loop could be turned into a statement and everything still works. So I wonder why and what version should really be preferred?

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);

    loop {
        println!("Please input your guess.");

        let mut guess = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        println!("You guessed: {}", guess);

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }
        } // <=== here should it be ended as statement (;) or not?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match`, `if`, `loop`, and other expressions that have `{}` blocks are treated specially by the Rust compiler. When these expressions occur as [expression statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#expression-statements), that is, *not* as part of a larger expression, and the type of the expression that has the block is `()`, you do not have to put `;` after it to separate it from a following statement.

This is not the case for expression statements *without* blocks, which always must be separated from the following statement (if one exists) by `;`, even if their type is `()`.

Because this rule exists, **it is usual in Rust *not* to put `;` after `match`, `if`, `unsafe`, etc. when they are used only for side effects**, or after `for` and `while` loops (which are always used only for side effects, since they always return `()`).

That said, both rustfmt and Clippy seem to be fine with the extra `;`, so if you prefer it there for aesthetic reasons, you're unlikely to offend anyone by using it.

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, loop blocks expect a "return" type of the empty type `()`. This is the type that's returned when you end with a statement and don't return anything at all (e.g. `{f();}`). `println!` returns the empty type, so the code you posted works either way, however I would say it makes more sense to end it with a semicolon.